# Error de carga de imágenes con FFImageLoading - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto `Xamarin.Android`; mis imágenes (sea sola o en el RecyclerView) no se cargan con `FFImageLoading`, me tira la imagen del `ErrorPlaceholder`.

Empecé a desmembrar la app pensando que era que cargaba muchas cosas al inicio, revise los links de las imágenes, revise el consumo del WiFi, todo tratando de encontrar el por que de este error que inicio de un tiempo para acá.

Encontré este [hilo](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1526) que hace mención a algo similar.

Hacen mención del error y recomiendan: "**Instalar `SkiaSharp` en el proyecto Android**". Muchos usuarios dan fe de que al intentar eso les funciona correctamente, sin embargo no me queda claro que hacer después de instalar el nuget para que me funcione. Yo ya instale el Nuget SkiaSharp, el SkiaSharp Views y el SkiaSharp Forms.

También en otro hilo recomiendan usar esta linea de código ya que, al parecer, hay un bug con `FF` y es debido a un certificado `SSL` y los links que llevan `https`.

Codigo recomendado para el `MainActivity`:

```
ImageService.Instance.Initialize(new FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration
                { HttpClient = new HttpClient() });
```

Actualmente muestro las imagenes de esta forma, y este metodo me funcionaba hace unos meses sin ningun problema, pero ahora es una loteria, a veces va bien pero usualmente va mal:

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(URLImage)
.Retry(3, 250)
.LoadingPlaceholder("LoadingImage", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
.ErrorPlaceholder("LoadingImage", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
.Into(cardview.imgIcon);
```

Busque demos y tutoriales de alternativas a FFImageLoading pero sin buenos resultados.

**EDIT:**

Paquete Nuget de `FFImageLoading` versión: `2.4.11.982` (ultima)

El 90% de mis usuarios activos tiene Android `11 y 12`. Y me da el problema en todos ellos.

Una de las varias URL con que da el problema: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/vWYpsSMMuMzFKAd7QmX5xwvM4dw.jpg`

Comment: Hola, cual es el mensaje que se despliega en el LogCat=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como alternativa a `FFImageLoading` puedes utilizar `Picasso`, funciona bastante bien y contiene el `PlaceHolder` que es lo que hace que FF se vea super rápido.

Adaptado a tu consulta quedaría algo así:

```
Picasso.Get()
.Load(URLImage)
.Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.LoadingImage)
.Fit()
.CenterCrop()
.Error(Resource.Drawable.LoadingImage)
.Into(cardview.imgIcon);
```

Necesitaras el Nuget:

```
using Square.Picasso;
```

Dejame saber si te funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta configuración al iniciar:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

ImageService.Instance.Initialize(new Configuration()
{
    HttpClient = httpClient,
    VerboseLogging = false,
    VerbosePerformanceLogging = false,
    VerboseMemoryCacheLogging = false,
    VerboseLoadingCancelledLogging = false,
});
```

Sería importante especificar en tu pregunta lo siguiente para encontrar pronto la respuesta:

- Versión de FFImageLoading.
- ¿En qué dispositivos falla?
- Si es posible, la URL de la imagen.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución, las preguntas o aclaraciones se realizan como comentario, revisar [answer] , saludos.